# Highlighting ListViewItem background color by code

Tags: c#, winforms

If I click on an item of a list view by mouse, the color becomes that "highlight" color BUT if I do it by code like this:
 *( MultiSelect should be True and Also I set HideSelection to False)*

```
myListView1.Items[2].Selected = true;
```

then it will be GRAY...bad! I want it to be the same highlight color when I manually click on them by mouse :(

I also tried adding this code but that didn't work either, Still gray

```
myListView1.Items[2].BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Blue;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the behaviour of the ListView when it has selected items, but it is **not** focused.

So, to get the 'blue' colour you are after, just add this;

```
listView1.Focus();
```

Comment: Both Works and Doesn't work! In my case it works because I am writing it in SELECT ALL, so all items should get selected BUT It doesn't work if I set a few items as selected for example items 2,3,6 ..then calling focus will highlight ALL items from 2 to 6 so 2,3,4,5,6

Comment: That doesn't happen for me - are you sure that only items 2,3,6 are Selected? Check the ListView.SelectedIndices property.

Comment: yep you are right. Not sure how it happened that time. Good solution. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

can you try this please in your listview's SelectedIndexChanged event ?

```
ListViewItem lv = YourListview.GetItemAt(YourListView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).X, YourListView.PointToClient(Cursor.Position).Y);

// this kind of Control.GetItemAt() works everywhere you need to find your mouse position ;)

// if you need to find position for screen (i.e. if you want to show a messagebox at the center of screen) you can use PointToScreen instead of PointToClient

 if (lv == null) 
 { 
   return; 
 }

else if (yourfirstpossibility == true)
{
  lv.Selected = true;
  lv.BackColor = Color.FromKnownColor(KnownColor.ButtonHighLight);

 // or which color you prefer. FromKnownColor retrieves system colors which you can see in backcolor / forecolor property => "system" named palette

}
```

a little bit different(more complicated) of this code i use in item_checked event for my listview.. hope it helps you..

Comment: @RJLohan Hmm.. yes you are right..Thank you to warn me..

about the question.. i thought / understood as he wants to change just backcolor..

Comment: This isn't an answer, it should be a comment (except it's too long, of course.)

Comment: @ErnestFriedman-Hill yes i know.. it should be a comment.. first i thought and wrote few words to comment without sent, but then thought that better is to give code sample if his need was this, to had an example in hand..   But anyway thank you to remind the ethic-rules..